# Was "Is this a pigeon?" from The Brave Fighter of Sun Fighbird, inspired by Bambi?

Tags: anime, inspiration, disney

Is what has now become a [famous meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/is-this-a-pigeon), Yutaro Katori, a human android asks:

[image: Yutari Katori holding out a hand towards a butterfly]

> Is this a pigeon?

When seeing a butterfly, as they're still learning to recognise the difference.

On watching the much earlier Bambi, I recognised a strikingly similar scene. Bambi also mistakes a butterfly for a bird:

[image: four panels each showing a frame from the original Bambi movie, where the rabbit Thumper teaches Bambi that a butterfly is not a bird]

Has Katsuyoshi Yatabe or anybody else involved in the production claimed an explicit inspiration?